# ljmp (in 64-bit mode) is rejected by #GP(0). Why?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

The code is minimal:

- Setup GDT with 2 entries (NULL and code descriptor).
- Attempt to far-jmp into the newly-installed code section.

But I get a #GP(0), for that last step.
why?

Here is the code, (running from **already** in 64-bit mode):

```
call    do_lgdt           # 'do_lgdt' is defined at the bottom
push    $(1<<3)           # Push code-selector,TI=0,RPL=0
lea     func(%rip),%rax   # The (relocated) address of 'func'
push    %rax              # Push it.
ljmp    *(%rsp)           # FAILS!!! #GP(0) (error code 0).

func:
jmp     .                 # Hang


do_lgdt:
lea     gdt(%rip),%rax    # The (relocated) address of 'gdt'.
                          # 'gdt' is defined at the bottom.
push    %rax              # Base
pushw   $(gdt_end-gdt-1)  # Limit
lgdt    (%rsp)
add     $0xa,%rsp         # Re-align the stack.
ret                       # Thanks @mevets..

.align 8                  # Thanks @PeterCordes
gdt:
.quad 0x0000000000000000  # NULL Descriptor
.quad 0x00a09a0000000000  # limit: 0x0000 (Ignored. Thanks @MichaelPetch)
                          # base : 0x0000
                          # type :    0xa (code/data=1,non-conforming,exec,accessed=0)
                          #      :    0x9 (system=1,DPL=0,present=1)
                          # limit:    0x0 (Ignored. Thanks @MichaelPetch)
                          #      :    0xa (avl=0,l=1,d=0,granularity=1)
                          # base :   0x00

gdt_end:
```

Comment: ljmp (opcode 0xea) is illegal in x86-64.

Comment: @marianok is correct. Usually what people do is push flags, selector, address and then do an `iretq` . `iretq` was originally recommended by the AMD64 documentation. This also works for changing into user mode.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I Still get (for iret) #GP(0). Same for lcall (0xff/3).

Comment: With a 64-bit GDT the base and limit are 0

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ok. But ignored anyway..

Comment: Do you have a complete project we can look at one something like github?

Comment: Basically, this is the complete "OS" that i test (Except a few lines for UEFI setup and relocation, and a simple fonts "module" for debugging). Oh and a nop with limited debugging output for IDT entries...

Comment: I think you need ljmpl. The SDM lists both jmp m16:32 and jmp m16:64 as valid in 64-bit mode, the latter with REX.W.

Comment: Turns out ljmpl doesn't cause gas to put rex.w. You can put it explicitly.

Comment: @prl: I think you'd want `ljmpq` to get REX.W=1 after pushing `rax`, if that isn't the default.  But good point!  Check the asm and see what operand-size your disassembler says (especially in Intel-syntax mode, where it normally says `qword ptr [mem]`.  It's disappointing that gas accepted bare `ljmp` without an operand-size suffix when it's ambiguous.

Comment: I just checked some working 64-bit code of mine and it uses ljmp without rex.w with a 32-bit offset.

Comment: @prl: so `push %rax` / `movw $(1<<3), 4(%rsp)` / `ljmpl *(%rsp)`?

Comment: @Peter, yeah good guess, but gas says invalid suffix for ljmpq.

Comment: @Peter, if rax is known to fit in 32 bits (as it is in my code) then that works. Otherwise, rex.w is needed.

Comment: objdump says FWORD PTR both with and without REX.W. So that's an indication that I'm wrong, but I wouldn't call it conclusive.

Comment: @prl If you mean ljmp (FF/5), That's exactly what I've done.
Adding `.byte 0x48` (REX.W) prefix - is futile (for this opcode), when already in 64-bit mode,

Comment: No, I don't think it is. The operand is m16:32 without REX.W.

Comment: Just an observation about JMP m16:64 . It isn't supported on all processors (ie: the original AMD64 instruction set) so AMD discouraged its usage for compatibility reasons. If m16:32 is doable then it will work. Otherwise the usage of `retfq` or `iretq` were recommended.

Answer (score 3):

**GAS assembles `ljmp *(%rsp)` without a REX prefix, so the operand size is `m16:32`**.  Long mode also allows [a `m16:64` form for far `jmp` (`REW.W FF /5`)](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/JMP), but doesn't *dis*-allow the 16:32 form.

GAS unfortunately doesn't warn about an ambiguous operand-size when `ljmp` is used with no suffix, and binutils 2.29.1 seems not to even understand the REX form.  It doesn't accept `ljmpq`, but it does accept `ljmpl` (as the non-REX form).

First-gen AMD64 CPUs (AMD K8) didn't support the REX.W `m16:64` form of `jmp`, and binutils was presumably never updated when it was introduced.  Pushing operands for `iretq` or `retfq` [was recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219035/ljmp-in-64-bit-mode-is-rejected-by-gp0-why/48220393?noredirect=1#comment83422903_48219035) if you needed a 64-bit target address, and maybe still is in AMD manuals for compat reasons.  If this was your only bug, and [`iretq` didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219035/ljmp-in-64-bit-mode-is-rejected-by-gp0-why/48220393?noredirect=1#comment83420459_48219035), then you used it wrong.

---

In your GAS source, I used

```
    .byte 0x48      # REX.W
    ljmp  *(%rsp)   # m16:64
```

---

In NDISASM syntax, the two forms are:

```
0000004F  48FF2C24          jmp far [rsp]

0000004F  FF2C24            jmp dword far [rsp]
```

---

In `objdump` output (presumably the same syntax GAS accepts as input):

```
# non-REX m16:32
f:   ff 2c 24                jmp    FWORD PTR [rsp]
f:   ff 2c 24                ljmp   *(%rsp)


# REX.W m16:64
f:   48 ff 2c 24             rex.W ljmp *(%rsp)
f:   48 ff 2c 24             rex.W jmp FWORD PTR [rsp]
```

---

The other alternative (if your pointer will also be in the low 32 bits) maybe saves a couple code bytes (although `movw imm16` + the addressing mode is longer than `push imm8`, so maybe not).

```
push  %rax
movw  $(1<<3), 4(%rsp)     # rewrite the top half of what you pushed
ljmpl *(%rsp)              # m16:32
```

---

Also note that if your code runs with interrupts disabled, your `do_gdt` function can `push %rax` and then store to `-2(%rsp)` instead of doing a word push.  Although again that's probably not actually smaller.  But for code-size you can restore the stack with a single `pop` instead of 2.  (`pop` + `popw` would still be shorter (3B total) than `add $10, %rsp` (4B total)).

---

Credit to @prl for spotting the `m16:32` problem, I just took the time to write it up and check what two disassembles do.

Comment: There seems to be an error in the SDM, which is why I was not sure of this answer at first. The SDM says that the jmp instruction's operand size is fixed at 64 bits. Perhaps the statement was intended to refer to near jumps only.

Comment: @prl The manual lists both the m16:32 and m16:64 encodings as valid. I think the "The instruction’s operation size is fixed at 64 bits." just means that the destination is always RIP not EIP. It continues with "If a selector points to a gate, then RIP equals the 64-bit displacement taken from gate; else RIP equals the zero-extended offset from the far pointer referenced in the instruction." so it's both talking about far jumps and 32-bit memory operands.

Comment: @Ross, thanks, I somehow overlooked the part with "zero-extended".

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn’t there be a ret in do_lgdt?  Otherwise you will execute gdt...

Comment: Right. Fixed it.

Comment: @marianok: And does the `ljmp` work now that it's being reached?  Does it matter if you `.p2align 3` before the `gdt:`?  Have you used a debugger (like BOCHS) to single-step your kernel?  Can you tell if it's the far jump itself that faults, or maybe the first instruction after the jump is not what you expected, and it's faulting?  (i.e. check RIP).

Comment: @PeterCordes Align still didn't do the trick. I can see the ljmp instruction address on top of the stack of the IDT handler (for #GP).

Comment: @PeterCordes base and limit fields are ignored. Anyway, changing to 0 still didn't do the trick.